# Website very slow in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

Why is our website very slow in Firefox? JS is already compressed and CSS is also compressed, but it loads very, very slow and we can't find why.

This is our website URL: http://www.tuxx.nl/planning/

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: I can see you have lots of different scripts, try to disable one by one and test to find out which one is actually causing the page to go slowly in FF. There is not much you can do but optimizing the JS more and remove the unnecessary lines especially the ones that you found out is causing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install this plugin for firefox called PageSpeed from google it will give you some tips :

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/download.html

and using this plugin on your website gives good results - 87/100

From the results :

41.9% of CSS (estimated 28.6kB of 68.2kB) is not used by the current page.

Using Firebug (another firefox plugin) I can see the following from the Net page - this shows what downloads when the page is loaded in the browser

Your site is 3.6 MB !!!!! Thats why its slow !!!

http://media.adrcdn.com/ads/Belastingdienst/37353138/19817/fiets_vid.flv is 1.7 MB

Reduce your page size

Comment: Thanks, but we can't remove that advertorial, so we need to load that.

Comment: @Kevin you have a couple of options a) reduce the size b) dont load it (not really a choice) c) have a slow page ......